# Create a DataContext and provide an API Key

Tags: entity-framework, api-key, wcf-data-services

i need some help with the following:

i have a wcf data service with some [api authorization mechanism](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-How-to-do-API-Key-Verification-with-a-WCF-WebHttp-REST-service/).
that works, if i enter the service url in the browser. it validates the api key and gives me data.

in another project, i added the service url as a service reference and like to instanciate a EntityFramework DataContext object, but what i wanted was, that the given URI to the constructor of that DataContext needs to have an api-key in there.

if i try to pass that api key as a query-parameter, i get an error: "Expected an absolute, well formed http URL without a query or fragment."

ok that message points out clearly what i did wrong, but how can i get the apiKey included?

greets,
chris

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer on [social.msdn.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/adodotnetdataservices/thread/226c47f7-f7bc-4450-8dff-e1136e8404ba). Basically, you need to use the AddQueryOption method of a resource proxy, like:

`SomeService.SomeResource.AddQueryOption("apikey", "1234")`

Comment: thank you. i didn't expected any answer here :) i will try that later and give feedback

Comment: No problem. I've struggled with this myself and it was surprisingly hard to find the answer on google.